# Merge [labwindows] and [CVI]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

I was looking at questions with the [labwindows](/questions/tagged/labwindows) tag and then realized a separate [cvi](/questions/tagged/cvi) tag existed. I always see this product called LabWindows/CVI as one entity, as shown in its [description](http://www.ni.com/lwcvi/what_is.htm) from NI.

To me it would make the most sense to replace [cvi](/questions/tagged/cvi) and [labwindows](/questions/tagged/labwindows) with a single [labwindows-cvi](/questions/tagged/labwindows-cvi) tag.

Comment: Is [tag:labwindows] OK as the master tag?  [tag:labwindows-cvi] would only be needed if there are different flavors of [tag:labwindows], as in [tag:labwindows-foo] and [tag:labwindows-bar]

Comment: yes, i agree with that justification.